# How to get _data:protected on printing customer data in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, customer, array

How to access this value from array **`[value] => 11113610`** ?

```
 Array
 (
 [is_saml] => Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
    (
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [attribute_code] => is_saml
                [value] => 1
            )

    )

[uwid] => Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
    (
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [attribute_code] => uwid
                [value] => rs-build
            )

    )

[student_number] => Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
    (
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [attribute_code] => student_number
                [value] => 11113610
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting the array data in **`$response`** variable.
You can get it by decoding first the response:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```

And then echo or save it to a variable like this:

```
echo $data['student_number']['_data:protected']['value'];
```

And for getting all of it in a response, use **`foreach loop`**:

```
foreach($data as $key => $item){
   echo $item['_data:protected']['value'].'<br>';
}
```